# How to Install Odoo 9 on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: software-installation, python, odoo

I'm using ubuntu 16.04 and I wanna use odoo 9. can you guys tell me how or maybe recommend a good tutorial?

if it's possible include the python installation too.

thanks

Comment: `if it's possible include the python installation too.` Python comes with Ubuntu by default, you don't need to install none

Comment: I am not sure if the question is a duplicate of that other question. Similar or same answer does not mean it is the same question.

Answer (score 1):

The installation process was fairly simple as instructed in the [official website](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/9.0/setup/install.html). I'm copying here the installation process of Community Edition. Please refer to the official installation guide for further requirement.

```
wget -O - https://nightly.odoo.com/odoo.key | sudo apt-key add -
echo "deb http://nightly.odoo.com/9.0/nightly/deb/ ./" >> sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install odoo
```

I've changed the command so that you don't need to switch as root.

Here's an explanation of the three commands above. The first line downloads Odoo repository key and adds to apt's trusted key db. The second one adds the odoo 9's nightly repository to your Ubuntu's repository list and the final line updates the list and install odoo.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I don't see a problem with answering the question. Please do not indulge in personal attacks.

Answer (score 0):

My ubuntu is exact kylin 16.04.

I did these steps a month ago in a empty ubuntu 16.04 and copied to here, you are lucky ^.^

Just follow some steps as below:

===install postgresql===

odoo use postgresql rather than MySql,it is easy to install postgresql in ubuntu:

$`sudo apt-get install postgresql-client-9.5`

$`sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.5`

after that, enter postgresql:

$`sudo su – postgres`

$`psql`

after enter postgresql command line,change postgres password first:

$`\password postgres`

after that, create superuser odoo for use,each command end with ";", and replace [user] with your username:

$`CREATE USER odoo WITH PASSWORD '123456';`

$`ALTER USER odoo WITH SUPERUSER;`

$`CREATE USER [user] WITH PASSWORD '123456';`

$`ALTER USER [user] WITH SUPERUSER;`

after that click ctrl+D to log out, then type "exit" to return to normal terminal.

===install python and pip===

ubuntu16.04 include python initially. if not, refer to
[install python2.7](http://tecadmin.net/install-python-2-7-on-ubuntu-and-linuxmint/)
install pip as follows:

$`sudo apt update`

$`sudo apt install python-pip`

===install required python package===

just as follows, for my ubuntu kylin 16.04,those packages are needed:

$`sudo apt install libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev libevent-dev libsasl2-dev libldap2-dev postgresql-server-dev-9.5`

after that, just as written in the documentation of Odoo, enter the main directory where you can find requirement.txt, type:

$`pip install -r requirements.txt`

it takes some minutes to accomplish.

[install python packages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3XDZ2.png)

===try to run odoo!===

open terminal and enter the main directory like“/home/USER/odoo_booy/”, type:

$`python odoo.py`

Yes, it expects to run very good ^-^